# How can I change the value of an iteration within a for loop in python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, calculator

I am new to python. I have been coding a python calculator but floats are annoying because `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3` so I have been using the decimal module. I have coded a script to convert the floats from the input to a decimal. I have first formatted the input string and then splitted it into a list. I run my script (for loop) on this list (called evalvar) but whenever I change the value of the i (iteration) to overwrite evalvar, nothing happens.
Code:

```
evalvar = ["0.1", "+0.2"]
for i in evalvar:
    try:
        #i is now equal to "0.1"
        i = str("""Decimal('""" + i + """')""")
        #i is now equal to """Decimal('0.1')"""
    except SyntaxError:
        print(evalvar)
```

I have worked out the answer myself.
Instead of using `for i in evalvar` I have used `for i in range(len(evalvar))` and replaced all the `i`'s in my for loop with `evalvar[i]`.

Comment: You may use session

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by session?

Comment: Strings are immutable, you *can’t* change i in a way that’s reflected in evalvar. You could replace it by index instead. But note that creating the string isn’t actually creating a Decimal; if you’re planning to then `eval` that I’d strongly recommend you reconsider.

Comment: @IkramHasib what *do* you mean?

Comment: @jonrsharpe so I cannot permanently change the value of i from inside the for loop, how do i use the index?

Comment: This is not really a Pythonic code. You might go through some nice tutorials, just to get the basics of it. For example http://www.diveintopython.net/ or https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe dont worry worked it out :)

Comment: just to be sure: will you then use `eval(evalvar)` to execute the string you just generated ? Because if you want to do that, then there are a lot of better, cleaner, faster and safer ways to do the same thing. `eval` is to be avoided at all costs in Python

Comment: @Guillaume, I know what I'm doing with my eval(). The program I have coded requires eval() in many places but I have made sure that the content of eval() cannot contain user specific input.

Answer (score 0):

Rebinding the iteration variable (`i`) will of course not modify your `evalvar` list, and since strings are immutable you can not update it in place either. The solutions here are either to build a new list:

```
# use string formatting instead of concatenation (more readable)
# and use a list expression (idiomatic and more efficient)
evalvar = ["Decimal('{}')".format(value) for value in evalvar]
```

or to update the list in place using indices:

```
# `enumerate(sequence)` yields an `index, value` tuple
# for each item in `sequence`
for index, value in enumerate(evalvar):
    evalvar[index] =  "Decimal('{}')".format(value)
```

This being said, building code as strings and passing it to `eval` or `ast.literal_eval` (which I assume is your plan) is certainly not the best solution. You'd be better parsing your input to an `operand, operator, operand` triplet, build numericals from the operand and use the `operator` module for operations ie:

```
import operator
operations = {
    "+": operator.add,
    "-": operator.sub,
    "*": operator.mul,
    "/": operator.truediv
    }

def parse_exp(inp):
    parsed = [item.strip() for item in inp.split(" ")]
    operator = parsed.pop(1)
    operands = [Decimal(item) for item in parsed]
    return operator, operands

def eval_exp(inp): 
    operator, operands = parse_exp(inp)
    return operations[operator](*operands)

def main():
    inp = "0.1 + 0.2"
    print(eval_exp(inp))
```